# How to update a plotly graph dash with different dropdowns

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to update a plotly graph dash with two different dropdowns as inputs.

This is my sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = {'category' : ['A','A','A','B','B','B'],'subcategory' : ['x', 'y', 'z', 'x1','y1','z1'],
      'x_coord' : [1, 2,3,2,2,2],'y_coord' : [1,3,2,1,3,2]}

df_test = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df_test
```

[image]

And what I pretend to do is if I select category A, that plots in a scatter all the correspondent points to the category, but If Also I select a subcategory that modifies the graph plotting only the correspondent category-subcategory point of the dataframe.

The code is below, and it works if I only add the callback of the first dropdown, but when I add the second callback to the subcategory it doesn't work. 
I am following the suggestions in the dash plotly tutorial where it says:

> ```
> A word of caution: it's not always a good idea to combine Outputs, even if you can:
>
> If the Outputs depend on some but not all of the same Inputs, keeping them separate can avoid unnecessary updates.
> If they have the same Inputs but do independent computations with these inputs, keeping the callbacks separate can allow them to run in parallel.
> ```
>
> [Dash documentation callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks)

But anyway if I put the output in separate callbacks or in the same I cannot make it work, here is the code that I am trying (using jupyter notebook):

```
import dash
import plotly as py
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from jupyter_plotly_dash import JupyterDash
py.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected = True)

app = JupyterDash('Test')

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown1',
                 options=[{'label':i, 'value':i} for i in df_test['category'].unique()]),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown2',
                 options=[{'label':i, 'value':i} for i in df_test['subcategory'].unique()]),
    dcc.Graph(id='graphic')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('dropdown2', 'options'),
    [Input('dropdown1', 'value')])

def update_drop2(selected_drop):
    filtered_df = df_test[(df_test.category == selected_drop)]
    return [{'label':i, 'value':i} for i in filtered_df['subcategory'].unique()]

@app.callback(
    Output('graphic', 'figure'),
    [Input('dropdown1', 'value')])

def update_figure(selected_drop):

    filtered_df = df_test[(df_test.category == selected_drop)]

    fig = go.Figure()

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=filtered_df.x_coord,y=filtered_df.y_coord, marker = dict(size=15, color='green'), mode='markers'))

    return fig


@app.callback(
    Output('graphic', 'figure'),
    [Input('dropdown2', 'value')])

def update_figure(selected_drop):

    filtered_df = df_test[(df_test.subcategory == selected_drop)]

    fig = go.Figure()

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=filtered_df.x_coord,y=filtered_df.y_coord, marker = dict(size=15, color='green'), mode='markers'))

    return fig

app
```

If I use multiple inputs on the callback like this:

```
@app.callback(
Output('graphic', 'figure'),
[Input('dropdown1', 'value'), Input('dropdown2', 'value')])

def update_figure(selected_drop1, selected_drop2):

    if not selected_drop2:
        filtered_df = df_test[(df_test.category == selected_drop1)]
    else: 
        filtered_df = df_test[(df_test.category == selected_drop1) & 
                      (df_test.subcategory == selected_drop2)]
    fig = go.Figure()

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=filtered_df.x_coord,y=filtered_df.y_coord, 
    marker = dict(size=15, color='green'), mode='markers'))

    return fig
```

It works better (or more near what I pretend), but however when I switch between categories I see no data.

Thanks in advance for your help and reccomendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problems the trick is to add to the second dropdown an option `all`. Then I wanted on the second dropdown to show only the subcategories in the given category. So I actually use 2 callbacks for dropdowns and 1 callback for the plot.

**app.py**

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

df = pd.DataFrame({'category' : ['A','A','A','B','B','B'],
                   'subcategory' : ['x', 'y', 'z', 'x1','y1','z1'],
                   'x_coord' : [1, 2,3,2,2,2],
                   'y_coord' : [1,3,2,1,3,2]})

# lists of categories
options1 = sorted(df["category"].unique().tolist())

# dictionary of category - subcategories
all_options = df.groupby("category")["subcategory"].unique()\
                .apply(list).to_dict()

# we add as first subcategory for each category `all`
for k, v in all_options.items():
    all_options[k].insert(0, 'all')


app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='first-dropdown',
        options=[{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in all_options.keys()],
        value=options1[0]
    ),

    html.Hr(),

    dcc.Dropdown(id='second-dropdown'),

    html.Hr(),

    dcc.Graph(id='display-selected-values')
])

# the following two callbacks generate a dynamic 2 option

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('second-dropdown', 'options'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('first-dropdown', 'value')])
def set_2_options(first_option):
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in all_options[first_option]]


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('second-dropdown', 'value'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('second-dropdown', 'options')])
def set_2_value(available_options):
    return available_options[0]['value']


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('display-selected-values', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('first-dropdown', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('second-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_graph(selected_first, selected_second):
    if selected_second == 'all':
        ddf = df[df["category"]==selected_first]
    else:
        ddf = df[(df["category"]==selected_first) &
                 (df["subcategory"]==selected_second)]

    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(x=ddf["x_coord"],
                   y=ddf["y_coord"],
                   marker = dict(size=15, color='green'),
                   mode='markers'))
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8051)
```

Comment: what is set_2_value function doing in this case? Not clear...would you mind elaborating?